# Context and normal menus appear to left instead of the right like they used to

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

Why are some context menus and menus suddenly screwed up? What I mean is, they've always opened up to the right, but now they're facing the left??? It's really getting on my nerves. I cannot stand it any longer. It's extremely painful to look at:
[image]

I have not installed any weird junk on my PC. It's a fresh install of Windows 8.1.

Comment: Please provide language information about the installation.  If its a fresh installation of Windows 8.1 then its likely a setting thats been enabled.

Comment: Is your device a Tablet?

Comment: Sorry guys for my delayed reply. The language info is US-English and no, it's not a tablet. It's an all-in-one pc.

Comment: @Tommy Then try my answer. Its for a PC

Comment: Shouldn't matter if it's a table or not - all-in-one is likely a touch screen as well, so the Tablet extensions are likely enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting called **'Handedness'** in Windows which must have been corrupted in your case. In order to change this follow these steps :

- Press Win+R to bring the Run dialogue box.
- Paste the following command into the provided field :

> shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}

[image]

- Press OK.
- You will get **Tablet PC settings** (Don't mind if your device is a tablet or not).
- Select the **Other** tab.
- In the **Handedness** section check the **Left Handed** option and press OK.

[image]

Voila! This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have it in "right-handed" tablet mode.  This is likely the default if you've got a touch-screen.

To change the setting:

1. Control Panel
2. Search for 'tablet'
3. Open 'Tablet PC Settings'
4. Change the handedness setting in the General tab

Directions summarized from: http://www.articulate.com/support/video-encoder-09/drop-down-menus-open-to-the-left-in-windows-8